# Regex pattern for length greater than 5

Tags: regex, shell

```
echo "bar,320,1530596475337.d94e12fe7ad127ec28e694123a9708d3.," \
    | grep "[a-zA-Z0-9,\.]{5,}"
```

This is not matching the string I provided. What am I doing wrong in my regex to match the given string?

Comment: Use `grep -E "[a-zA-Z0-9,.]{5,}"`

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different regexp dialects.  `grep` per default uses a dialect which does not support the braces as you use them.

Try again using option `-P` which switches to Perl dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Grep defaults to the [Basic Regular Expression (BRE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) dialect, which requires that the curly braces for a quantifier are escaped: `\{5,\}`.

More remarks:

- You don't have to escape characters within a bracket expression, so you can just use `[.]` and don't need `[\.]` to include a period in it.
- [Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) don't require escaping the curly braces and you can use `{5,}`. Indicate that you're using ERE with the `grep -E` option.
- Depending on your locale, `a-z` might not be just the lowercase Latin alphabet. Instead of `a-zA-Z0-9`, you can use the POSIX character class `[:alnum:]`.
- You're using double quotes. Even though in this case it doesn't make a difference, you usually will want your regex in single quotes to avoid surprises due to parameter expansion.

All in all, I'd use the command as follows:

```
grep -E '[[:alnum:],.]{5,}'
```